# how to, on window load, smooth scroll to bottom and when complete, scroll back up and loop?

Tags: jquery

What's the best way to accomplish a loop of this animation while adding an animation to go back to the top?

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 110000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Alright! With @void help. I got this working.

```
var x = 110000; // This is 110sec.
var y = 100000; // This is 100sec.

$(window).load(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, x, function() {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: (0) }, y);
    });

    setInterval(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, x, function() {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: (0) }, y);
    });
    }, x+y);

});
```

shoot. This isn't looping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can loop.

```
    var x = 110000; // This is 110sec.
    var y = 100000; // This is 100sec.

    $(window).load(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, x, function() {
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, y);
        });

        setInterval(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, x, function() {
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, y);
        });
        }, x+y);

    });
```

Comment: Ah, yes, definitely. set the animations as variables and loop those with the interval, but what about scrolling back to the top? any ideas?